# Formatting a date in moment.js gives 1/1/2016

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

```
function getData(thing, thingDate) {
    var fThingDate = moment(thingDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    return getAPIData('/api/things?thing=' + thing + '&thingDate=' + fThingDate).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
}
```

`thingDate` is `2016-04-30T00:00:00` (according to the debugger) but when I format it, `fThingDate` becomes `1/1/2016`. Why is it going to the 1st of the year? And how do I stop it?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/h37cL4Lo/. Inspect your variables more to make sure they are what you think.

Comment: Can't reproduce your result. You will get that result if moment.js only sees the year, "2016". You should always pass the format when parsing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like momentjs has an issue when the datetime is a string in the format: `2016-04-30T00:00:00`. I ran this in IE 10 and Windows Server 2012 Std.

But this seemed to solve it:

```
function getData(thing, thingDate) {
    var fThingDate = moment(new Date(thingDate)).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    return getAPIData('/api/things?thing=' + thing + '&thingDate=' + fThingDate).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
}
```

NOTE: Before blaming it on IE, it seems that a few people have ran into the same problem in the past as well.